# SQL LocalDB Security for Desktop Applications

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, localdb

I'm developing a Windows desktop application by using .Net Framework and SQL LocalDB as database.
If any user find the database file, and attach it into his own server, he could access all the data.
Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: LocalDB is "their own server". If you are intending to put the database on the user's machine then you cannot prevent them from accessing it. If you need  that kind of security then you need a database server with access controls.

Comment: There is no way to restrict their access outside the application environment? @crowcoder

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions

Answer (score 0):

No.

"If user database files are stored in a shared location, the database can be opened by anyone with file system access to that location by using an instance of LocalDB that they own."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions